# setting [src] in base64 format for <img> in ionic2/angular2 not working

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, base64, ionic-native

I am trying to set image src with base64 image dynamically but it doesn't work in ionic2/angular 2 for an android emulator. I retrieved the image from externalrootdirectory in ionic2 in base64 format. Please find below code snippet:

Here, imageSrc set in base64 format in .ts file.
If I set base64 string directly into .html file then it works. Base64 string directly used in following way:

But, I want to set image in base64 format dynamically for camera capture. Please let me know how set src at run time for

Thanks,

Comment: You forgot to add the code :-)

Comment: I am trying to set image src with base64 image dynamically but it doesn't work in ionic2/angular 2 for an android emulator. I retrieved the image from externalrootdirectory in ionic2 in base64 format. Please find below code snippet:
<p><img [src]="imageSrc"  /></p>
Here, imageSrc set in base64 format in .ts file. If I set base64 string directly into .html file then it works. Base64 string directly used in following way:
<p><img src="data:image/*;charset=utf-8;base64,/9j/4AAQS ... /></p>
But, I want to set image in base64 format dynamically for camera capture. 
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You need to use  tag like this

```
<img src="data:image/*;base64,{{imageUrl}}" />
```

hope this works for you

Comment: I have given imageUrl as base64 data received after encoding of jpg image from file path. But it doesn't work. Can I give directly src path as in format /storage/emulator/0/....etc? Please let me know the way to set src dynamically for img in ionic2.

Comment: i think the problem is for <img> tag. can you use <ion-img> tag for this?